# Customizing expand/collapse icons for tree view

Tags: ag-grid

Any one have experience in customizing the ag-grid expand/collapse icons in the tree view.  I've trolled SO, and the ag-grid support portal with no luck.
Discussion inside https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#gsc.tab=0 did not appear to cover.

Current behavior shows +/-.
I would like to change the appearance to (my company standard) of up/down v 
[up/down arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X3Et.png)

Code would be great, but declarative no would be valuable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have just missed [this page of the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-icons/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0).

```
var gridOptions = {
    ...
    icons: {
        groupExpanded: '<img src="down.png" style="width: 15px;"/>',
        groupContracted: '<img src="up.png" style="width: 15px;"/>'
    }
}
```